# Eclipse Program is crashing / Java TM is not responding

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here][1]I was just starting to follow a Tutorial series on how to create a Java 3D game engine but when the Youtuber is running the following code, his program runs smoothly and doesn't care about anything. But when I run the exact same code, it firstly has like 2 FPS and then crashes with the error message "Java (TM) binary SE is not responding...

The Tutorial Series:
*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBK-lb-k-rs&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5&index=4*

The Code:

````
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class Input {

    public static final int NUM_KEYCODES = 256;

    private static ArrayList<Integer> currentKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> downKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> upKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //I call  this method in my main method and this is also what causes the lag
    // I think it has to do with the indexing of the keys, but on his computer, it runs smoothly
    public static void update() {

        // these 3 blocks of code clear out the Arraylists above and check if a is pressed / pressed down / or released
        upKeys.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYCODES; i++)
            if(!getKey(i) && currentKeys.contains(i))
                upKeys.add(i);

        downKeys.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYCODES; i++)
            if(getKey(i) && !currentKeys.contains(i))
                downKeys.add(i);

        currentKeys.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYCODES; i++)
            if(getKey(i))
                currentKeys.add(i);
    }

    public static boolean getKey(int keyCode) {
        return Keyboard.isKeyDown(keyCode);
    }

    public static boolean getKeyDown(int keyCode) {
        if(downKeys.contains(keyCode))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean getKeyUp(int keyCode) {
        if(upKeys.contains(keyCode))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7POD.jpg
````

Comment: How have you determined that this class is responsible for the problem?

Comment: Well, I changed the ```NUM_KEYCODES``` from 256 to 2 and it ran smoothly even if it didn't detect any changes from my keyboard...

Comment: It looks like this code is doing rather a lot of unnecessary work to rebuild three ArrayLists from scratch every time `update` is called (presumably once per frame), and these ArrayLists are only used for the `contains` method (which is strange because ArrayLists aren't a good choice if you only want to do membership tests). Either this is a very bad tutorial, or your code is not actually the same as it; but I am not going to spend the time to watch the video to find out. How have you verified that your code is the "exact same"?

Comment: I just checked it like 3 times and watched the video about 10 times and also rewrote the code a couple of times... but on his computer, it seems to work just fine as if it was nothing for his CPU

Comment: In that case, all I can suggest is that you should look for a better tutorial. This is bad code and it's better not to learn how to write bad code.

Comment: @kaya3 could you recommend a tutorial series around 'making a 3D Java Game Engine from scratch'?